# Automatically change input language

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, textbox, urdu

i am trying to build an web application in which i want to take inputs in two language english and urdu.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txturdu" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtenglish" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

So what i am trying to do is when i click on textbox (txturdu) it automatically takes input in urdu language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Listen to key press event
2 - Detect pressed key code [example](http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)
3 - Translate the pressed key code to the Urdu character (may be you can use Array[code,character] here)
4 - Add the character to yourtextbox.Text
don't forget to call event.preventDefault();
to prevent adding the character in the default language again